# Api request from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request

It is necessary to obtain data from https://forkdelta.io using api https://github.com/forkdelta/backend-replacement/tree/master/docs/api

Here is the code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
   const io = require('socket.io-client');
   socket = io.connect('https://api.forkdelta.com', { transports: 
   ['websocket'] });

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('socket connected');
    socket.emit('getMarket', {
        token: "0x6fff3806bbac52a20e0d79bc538d527f6a22c96b",
        user: "" });

});
socket.on('market', function(payload) {
    console.log(payload.orders.buys);
});

}).listen(3000);

console.log("Server has started.");
```

I save it in server.js and execute the command node server.js

I run the code at the link http: // localhost: 3000 from the local server - hangs

I run the code from here https://repl.it/repls/DeafeningBlushingAddons - successfully

Please help me figure out how to correctly run the code from the browser. Next, we intend to parse the data array and convert it to a table.

Comment: `Please help me figure out how to correctly run the code from the browser` ... The code you are posting cannot run from the browser directly, since it's a node.js script. The architecture suggests me that you are building a **middleware** between the web browser and the api.forkdelta.com REST API. If so, please post the whole code, including the client-side code, which might be relevant due to socket handling.

Comment: I have only one script server.js. I suggest client side must be here?

Comment: No. You are creating a web server and listening on port 3000. There **must** be a client side, which might be relevant later. That said, the above code should work as expected already, but the console log should be available on the **node console**, which is where you are running the script from, **NOT** the browser's console. What is unclear, to me, is what you want to achieve. You mentioned that you need to run that code from a **browser**. If so, **this won't work**, or at least not as you are currently expecting. Can you please specify what is the exact question?

Comment: The first I am intending to enter the some address in the browser then api call happens, then put response data into html table.

Comment: After I plan to have client side elements (e. g. buttons) which will make an API call (other api methods)to the node code and then display the response in a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the console from where you are executing this code, it is actually fetching the data you require...

This is what the data looks like

```
{ id: '0xd7ff1f49ffde2380b1fd42877b8ce573bfb2c1cace509b1edcb07e757fa13889_buy',
user: '0x5b38d2298666c89efe5f1819347a6004b93bbbe2',
state: 'OPEN',
tokenGet: '0x6fff3806bbac52a20e0d79bc538d527f6a22c96b',
amountGet: '3.50e+22',
tokenGive: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
amountGive: '3.500e+15',
expires: '104747875',
nonce: '1340442292',
v: 27,
r: '0xc929ec3f336b4641d84545d27764c43470946c3119221c856c8f72ac3f625edb',
s: '0x5a79fe5728fb47d22c837ae322bff8b43f3de638ddfa3ee5122bf344a0e507dc',
date: '2018-02-14T20:18:30.052233',
updated: '2018-10-02T10:06:53',
availableVolume: '3.15e+18',
ethAvailableVolume: '3.150000000',
availableVolumeBase: '3.150e+11',
ethAvailableVolumeBase: '3.150000000e-7',
amount: '-3.15e+18',
amountFilled: '0',
price: '1e-7' }
```

Comment: http://joxi.ru/8AnEMbOTjQG4p2  here is no response((.  The data you get it is exactly what I need, but requesting from browser!!!!

Comment: Check that space once you access localhost:3000 from the browser... it should start displaying the data...

Comment: See, there are multiple ways you can try to achieve what you want. One either having a client side code to request data from the above piece of code or have a templating engine on the server code itself to render the data that you're receiving. What are you intending to do? Are you planning on having a client side code which will make an API call to the node code and then display the response in a table?

Comment: The first I am intending to enter the some address in the browser then api call happens, then put response data into html table.

Comment: After I plan to have client side elements (e. g. buttons) which will make an API call (other api methods)to the node code and then display the response in a table

Comment: Ok, the flow would be as simple as this.... "the some address" that you're planning to enter in the browser should be the address of the client code which does not exist right now (so plan on setting up a basic client first) 

the client code would then internally hit the server code (which you currently have), it would get the data... then you should be handling the data on the client code (ie., display in a table or however you would like it)

what you are currently trying to do will probably not work. you are trying to enter the server's address in the browser which is wrong.